# Magento Extending Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have been trying for days to extend the abstract class

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract
```

I have tried the ways I have successfully extended non-abstract classes, with no luck. I need to do this because I have modified the filter.phtml file and this is where the template is set. So i basically just need a way to change the following function, without modifying any core files so it will be compatible when we update:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/layer/filter.phtml');
}
```

I do not want to just modify the core template, because this will get erased when we update. Any help or any other ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. I usually just edit the XML files, but this template is not called in an XML file and this is the only place I have found reference to it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is "class MyClass extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract".  However, it's clear the problem you're having is something else.  Until you can ask a better question no one is going to help you.  Not because they're mean, but because they have no idea what you want.

Comment: @AlanStorm, sorry but this was the best way I could explain the question. I went about it another way anyways...

Answer (score 1):

For this we need to use setPageSize function.

Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract class is responsible for setting filter template

You will override this Block class with your module’s class YourNamespace_YourModule_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract. So, the path of class YourNamespace_YourModule_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract is YourNamespace/YourModule/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php

So your New File - **Abstract.php** will be like

```
<?php
class YourNamespace_YourModule_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract extends  Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract
    {
        /**

         */

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('YourFolder/catalog/layer/filter.phtml');
    }

    }
```

Here is the xml code which is to be written in etc/config.xml for your custom module.

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer_filter_abstract>YourNamespace_YourModule_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract</layer_filter_abstract>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
<global>
```